# MVC + $.getJSON not calling controller in certain scenarios

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, getjson

We are developing application using MVC.

We have Check box list on the View and all the selected values(guids) in the checkbox list are being passed to the controller.

We have about 60 items displayed in the check box list.

When more than 50, to be precise when 51 itesm are selected a call is not made to the method in controler. If the number of selected item are equal or less than 50 then call is made.

Any suggestions?

```
View Code:
function fnSaveChanges(s, e) {
        debugger;
        var guidss = Chk_Client.GetSelectedValues();
        var UserID = m_UserID;
        var m_URLAction = '@Url.Action("SaveGuids")';
        $.getJSON(m_URLAction , { guidsFromView: String(guids), UserID: UserID }, saveGuids_Callback);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use Fiddler to examine the POST/GET values. Probably a clue there.

Comment: Thanks, we used .post instead of .getJSON and it works